# Multiseries graph using d3.v2.js

Tags: d3.js

We are plotting a multilinear graph using d3.v2.js .
We are using ordinal scale for x-axis and linear scale for y-axis as we have labels(string)  to be shown in x-axis
and numbers to be shown in y-axis.

In some cases graph appears to be fine , but in some cases it plots x-axis and y-axis independently  and y-axis values are not in sync with x-axis values.
Also plotting starts from 0 instead of first x-axis value.

Any pointers to this issue would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Please find the code below.

```
    function plotMOAGraph(data , sigPathways){
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;      

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal(
        (d3.range(0,sigPathways.length))).rangeBands([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)          
        .orient("bottom");


    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)          
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.pathway); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.score); });

    var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", 450 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "pathway"; }));             

      var entityNames = color.domain().map(function(name) {           
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {pathway: d.pathway, score: +d[name]};
          })
        };
      });


      x.domain(sigPathways);

      y.domain([
        d3.min(entityNames, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.score; }); }),
        d3.max(entityNames, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.score; }); })
      ]);


      svg.append("g")  
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)      
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", "9em")
        .attr("dx","40em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Pathways");


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")             
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", "-4em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Pathway Scores");

      var tooltip = d3.select("#graphDiv")
        .append("div")   
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
         ; 

      var rotateXAxis = function(d) {
            var name = d.substr(0, 15);
            if(name !== d) {
                name = name + " ... ";
            }
            var el = d3.select(this);                                               
            el.text('').attr("transform",  "rotate(-45)").attr("text-anchor", "end").on("mouseover", showTooltip).on("mouseout",hideTooltip);               
            var tspan = el.append('tspan').text(name);
            tspan.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '0');


        };

        svg.selectAll('g.x.axis g text').each(rotateXAxis);
        function showTooltip(d) {

            tooltip.text(d).style("position","absolute")
            .style("top",  (d3.event.pageY)-10+"px")
            .style("left",  (d3.event.pageX)-300+"px")
            .style("visibility", "visible")
            .style("font-size", "12px");            
        }

        function hideTooltip() {                
            tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");          
        }

      var entityName = svg.selectAll(".entityName")
          .data(entityNames)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "entityName");


      entityName.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
          return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name); });


      entityName.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.pathway) + "," + y(d.value.score) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify under what circumstances it doesn't work? What do you mean by x and y axis values being not in sync?

Comment: Thanks for the response Lars.

Comment: What I mean is x-axis first tick does not start from 0  , rather it starts after some distance from beginning of axis. Any idea why it happens so?

Comment: Since x-axis tick starts after some distance from start of the axis, plot ends before the last tick so y-axis and x-axis values do not look in synch.

Comment: In what circumstances do you see this behaviour?